# How to count used or unused function and method in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i have to count used or unused method or function. now i type the counting method code each method or function. how to count that it is used or unused method or function in briefly??

Private Sub tsbtRework_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tsbtRework.Click

Write_CountClick()

Comment: To be clear: you're asking for a code solution (since you've mentioned VB.NET) and not an IDE solution (since you haven't mentioned which IDE your using, e.g. Visual Studio, Rider, etc.), right?

Comment: hmm... there are a lot of 'vb file' in solution explorer. right? i just wonder  which file is using or which file is unusing in my program. could it check ?

Comment: OK, so you want to find this using... Visual Studio?

Comment: don't confuse methods and functions with event handlers. Also, you can search for the method name or you can use the IDE tools and find all references to the method.

Comment: yes. moreover i have to pick out click event that is using or unusing. now i make a counting method that it is used (Write_CountClick()) and type individual click event((( Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblLinkPlm.Click)))) is it best to pick out?